Need a good reference to study regularity of system of second order Elliptic PDEs
I am looking for a regularity estimate for the solution of a system of second order elliptic PDE's with Mixed Boundary conditions.

You might enhance your question by listing some of the references, e.g. Gilbarg and Trudinger, you’ve already had a look at and why you found them unsatisfactory.

Perhaps provide an explicit example including the boundary conditions. Unfortunately there are not many books on elliptic systems. You can try looking at the classic papers of Agmon, Douglis, Nirenberg.
